# Unable to get an output for sudoku solver using backtracking

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, sudoku, recursive-backtracking

I started working on a sudoku solver using backtracking and recursion. I am unable to print the solved Sudoku. I have tested the `possible(y,x,n)` method and it works. The program finishes with `Process finished with exit code 0` but without printing out the solved sudoku puzzle. I'm using python 3.7 with PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.3 as my IDE.

```
import numpy as np

grid = [[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [6, 0, 0, 1, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
        [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
        [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
        [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
        [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]]


def possible(y, x, n):
    global grid
    for i in range(9):
        if grid[y][i] == n:
            return False
    for i in range(9):
        if grid[x][i] == n:
            return False
    x0 = (x // 3) * 3
    y0 = (y // 3) * 3
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if grid[y0 + i][x0 + j] == n:
                return False
    return True


def solve():
    global grid
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if grid[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10):
                    if possible(y, x, n):
                        grid[y][x] = n
                        solve()
                        grid[y][x] = 0
                return
    print(np.matrix(grid))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    solve()
```

Comment: You have an early `return` statement in your `solve()` function which is why the line `print(np.matrix(grid))` doesn't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tested the possible(y,x,n) method and it works.

But it's broken:

```
if grid[x][i] == n:
```

Should be:

```
if grid[i][x] == n:
```

Next issue is the puzzle you're trying to solve, is broken!  The sixth column has two nines in it:

```
[., ., ., ., ., 0, ., ., .]
[., ., ., ., ., 9, ., ., .]
[., ., ., ., ., 0, ., ., .]
[., ., ., ., ., 0, ., ., .]
[., ., ., ., ., 3, ., ., .]
[., ., ., ., ., 0, ., ., .]
[., ., ., ., ., 0, ., ., .]
[., ., ., ., ., 9, ., ., .]
[., ., ., ., ., 0, ., ., .]
```

You might want to add a puzzle verifier to your set of functions.  In my example below, I use a different puzzle that's solvable, as it's hard to debug your code otherwise!

Finally, your `solve()` function is underwritten.  It shouldn't print the puzzle, but rather return a boolean indicating whether it solved the puzzle or not.  This result is then used in your backtracking, and at the end to determine if the puzzle is solvable or not.

Finally, read up on the `global` keyword, you're using it incorrectly.

```
import numpy as np

def possible(y, x, n):
    for i in range(9):
        if grid[y][i] == n:
            return False

    for i in range(9):
        if grid[i][x] == n:
            return False

    x0 = (x // 3) * 3
    y0 = (y // 3) * 3

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if grid[y0 + i][x0 + j] == n:
                return False

    return True

def solve():
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if grid[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10):
                    if possible(y, x, n):
                        grid[y][x] = n  # tentatively try n

                        solved = solve()
                        if solved:
                            return True  # solved recursively!

                        grid[y][x] = 0  # undo attempt at n
                
                return False  # no solution for this square

    return True  # no 0's to resolve, puzzle solved!

if __name__ == "__main__":
    grid = [
        [6, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0],
        [0, 7, 0, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 0],
        [0, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0],
        [0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 5, 0, 0, 7],
        [0, 6, 0, 9, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [7, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0],
        [0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0],
        [0, 0, 7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 8]
    ]

    if solve():
        print(np.matrix(grid))
    else:
        print("No solution!")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[[6 5 8 1 4 3 9 7 2]
 [4 7 1 2 5 9 8 3 6]
 [2 3 9 7 8 6 5 4 1]
 [3 9 2 6 1 5 4 8 7]
 [8 6 5 9 7 4 1 2 3]
 [7 1 4 3 2 8 6 9 5]
 [1 4 6 8 3 7 2 5 9]
 [9 8 7 5 6 2 3 1 4]
 [5 2 3 4 9 1 7 6 8]]
>
```